# Selenium webdriver: what is the latest version of chrome driver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried navigating to the Chrome driver website and saw that the latest release being documented was 2.22, but when I got to the index page, I saw that 2.9 was mentioned down the hierarchy.

Can somebody please help in understanding the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The versions on [the chromedriver download page](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) are sorted alphabetically, not numerically or chronologically. That means that `2.9` appears at the bottom of the page, which might make it look like the "last" or "most recent" version. The actual most recent version as of this writing is, in fact, `2.22`.

Answer (score 1):

Please find chrome driver here

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: murali, i am having confusion whether 2.22 is the latest version or 2.9. can you please clarify that?

Comment: 2.22 is latest. you can find here also http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/   Released 2016-06-04

Answer (score 0):

Use this Selenium site you have drivers for all browsers even for phone's.. Check it

http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ - You may find there chrome webdriver 2.22Version